# Can i export a JSON object to Excel in ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, json, export

i am already creating a "table" by having a list of json objects.  Is there any generic way i can export this to excel without a lot of custom coding for the details of the data itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible (or at least the way is unknown to me).

Moreover, from your other questions one can see that you use custom formatter in the jqGrid with different colors and so on. With respect of solution on the server side which use for example Open XML SDK 2.0 you are able produce a perfect Excel table with all formating features which you need. You can for example create a template for the output Excel table with formating features which you need and create a new Excel document based on the template with the filling the data mostly.